# SQL Server Divide Select top 1 Total Balance / Count of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My issue is that the Balance is the sum of City. I'd like to divide the Select top 1 Balance from #temp by the number of counts.

For example, my table is like

```
create table #temp
(
Source varchar(6),
City varchar(20),
Balance money
)

insert into #temp values ('NE1', 'Chicago', 1000.00)
insert into #temp values ('NE2', 'Chicago', 1000.00)
```

So in the example above, I'd see a table output like:

```
Source    Account    Balance    RelativeBalance
NE1       Chicago    1000       500
NE2       Chicago    1000       500
```

The relative Balance then is the 1000 divided by the count of Chicago, 2.

Note, there's not a split in the backend.

Comment: Could it happen / what if the balances were different?  In that case "select top 1 balance" partitioned by Account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use a window function:

```
select t.*, balance / count(*) over (partition by account)
from #temp t
```